# How do I get 50 reputation so I can comment on some of these posts? Also do badges count towards reputation and if so how much?

Tags: discussion, reputation, new-users, privileges

Help a newcomer out please. It's much appreciated.

Comment: Post valid questions, answers and suggest valid edits. Easiest way is answer a bounty question. Also please read [What is reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: @gnat I wanted to get my own feedback, I'm not sure what saying that this is a possible duplicate of someone else's post does for you, me, or anyone else as I downloaded this app half an hour ago. If I messed up or something could you let me know.

Comment: Since you provided no details all we can provide is general advice which we already have in other answers.

Comment: No, badges don't count towards your reputation.

Comment: I moved m answer to the proposed duplicate, but I had a look, and I can see that your only a member of here and SciFi; I assume you were talking about SciFi. In regards to "post good answers", [take a look at the few I have posted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/50447/gnemlock?tab=answers). I do not answer, much, but all but one have earned me enough reputation to post, on their own. I find SciFi like their analysis and proof, and (much to my joy) are far less serious (and critical) than other SE sites, such as Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Write a lot of answers to *new* questions.

Try to be the first.

Take care to the good quality (spelling, grammar).

Filter to the technologies most well known for you by their tags. List the newest, unanswered questions by these tags. Be the first answerer.

If you are not a professional of the field about a given site, but the site is a "hard" science site (like, for example, the physics SE), then you can do it better on the weekends. It is because the professionals of the area are mostly away on the weekends.

To write good answers is not enough, you have to write a *lot* of them. Thus, you have to optimize for quality * quantity, not only for one of them.

Don't bother downvotes, they are weak (-2) to the ups (+10). Only the count of the upvotes is important.

Also the pipe (accepted answer) is not very important: you have only a small chance to get it for an answer, it is only little bit stronger as an upvote (+15), and you can get at most one for an answer.

Don't bother also to the bounties, because they require a *lot* of work and you have only a little chance to get one. Instead trying to win bounties, you can get mostly more reputation by writing a lot of ordinary answers. But note, you have to optimize for *quality * quantity*, not only for one of them! (Writing many LQ answers would give you to answer ban, while investing not realistic effort into some answers which will remain unreacted is uneffective).

The length of your answer should be roughly 800 - 1000 bytes, here is the maximum of the "answer length / reputation got" ratio.

You will get most of your upvotes within a day, and get some in a week. In the next years, you will get lesser ups for an answer as you got on its first week of existence.

You can't get enough rep for questions: people here somehow don't like to vote up questions (and their ups worth only +5). The only way to get many rep is writing answers. And, writing a question also requires from you later a lot of work (reacting answers in comments, modify your question reacting the comments you got and so on). Writing questions for reputation is not effective.

---

If nothing works, you can find very bad quality, but somehow not deleted posts, for example by [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/668095/functional-illiteracy-detector) or [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/669320/functional-illiteracy-detector-most-upvoted-historical-posts) SEDE queries. Fixing their grammar and general quality can give you +2, which is not too many, and not a very high quality work, but it can be useful.

Anyways if you are a native English speaker, likely you can find a lot of posts where grammar/spelling corrections are needed.

This strategy is useful only if you are on a site where it is hard for you to get ups and you have no higher goals (for example, you want to get only to 50 or to 200).

Comment: Thank you I see what you're saying. I just saw the this app on the store and figured why not get it, but I do not know much about it. I tried to comment on a question and it said I need 50 reputation first so I figured I should post a question pertaining to this in hopes of possibly getting more reputation and well, help. As I read more through this, I've noticed that this site is mainly formal and I should refrain from being as informal as I was with my question if I hope to get reputation. Your answer and whomever edited it has been helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: @ChristianMotley My pleasure. Btw, the scifi SE is not a very friendly site, so it may be harder. I don't know them very well, but I think there also making questions can be more useful. What can be also useful: if you get to 200 *anywhere*, then you will get +100 bonus *everywhere*. Thus, you will be able to comment everywhere from that.

Answer (score 1):

> How the **hell do I** get

## #1. Be patient.

Don't think you are a Jon skeet

## Do

1. Provide good answers and be the first to answer.
2. If someone asks for clarification in your answer, clarify it.
3. Make good edit suggestions.
4. Ask good quality questions that have not been asked before and show some research effort.
5. Read the site's tour, how to ask for getting a clear idea about how to interact with the community and it will help you to provide quality content.

## Don't

1. Don't make comments as answers.
2. Don't suggest bad edits. Continuous rejection of suggested edit will bring you a temporary edit ban.
3. Don't ask questions that have been asked previously or don't show any research effort.

## The reputation

1. +10 for up vote in answer.
2. +5 for up vote in question
3. +2 for accepted suggest edit.
4. +15 for accepted answer.
5. +2 for accepting answer for your question(not self answer).
6. -2 for getting a down vote.

**Keep all this in mind and interact in good way with the community.**